# VSTS deploy to non-Azure cloud platform

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I've currently got an ASP.NET Core web application with EF that I am deploying to GearHost (a non-Azure cloud platform that was recommended by a user here) using a web deploy publish profile directly from Visual Studio. I'm looking to get CI/CD set up via VSTS so that the publish ability isn't restricted to one machine.

So far I've got the build stage set up, as the .NET Core template is all that's really needed. It's the deploy part that has got me stuck - all the templates (and indeed articles) that I can find relating specifically to .NET Core are focused on Azure or an IIS deployment, neither of which are really applicable here, and indeed Azure uses deploy tasks that are created specifically for it.

If it's relevant, GearHost provides FTP credentials which could potentially be used for a manual copy. Alternatively, is there any way I could use the VS2017 publish profile to create a release definition including appsettings.json transforms and EF migrations?

Comment: There seems to be an FTP upload task in the VSTS build process. Did you try that?

Comment: That could very well be what I need, I just had a look at it. Though at first glance this seems to just take the entire build artifact and dump it on the server, I'm not seeing any way I can incorporate appsettings.json replacement (for the DB connection string) or EF migrations, or indeed what remote directory should be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to deploy app to GearHost server, such as FTP, Publish Profile.

So, you can upload the published files (e.g. Create a publish profile with file system publish method) to GearHost server by using [FTP Upload task](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/ftp-upload).

You also could [download the publish profile with Web Deploy method and import to VS](https://www.gearhost.com/documentation/how-to-publish-your-app-from-visual-studio), then deploy app by using this publish profile. (MSBuild Arguments: `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=[publish profile file name]`)

Regarding appsettings.json transforms, you don’t need to transform appsettings.json file, the .net core project can retrieve the values from `appsettings.[environment].json` file per to the value of **ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT** system environment variable. [Working with multiple environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments)

Regarding EF migrations, you can configure it in publish profile and publish/deploy app with that publish profile.

Update:

Steps to call GearHost cloudsite:

1. Log in GearHost
2. Click API tab >Create a new API Key
3. Using Invoke-RestMethod

Simple code:

```
$url="https://api.gearhost.com/v1/cloudsites/[could site id]/stop"
 $APIID="[step 2]"
 $result=Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization=("bearer {0}" -f $APIID)} -ContentType "application/json"
```

Comment: You could also do the EF migrations by code on app start with switch via environment variable.

Comment: I'd thought about having appsettings.json files defined for environments but I am concerned that they will end up under source control, which as it is on a public GitHub repository is not really desirable due to connection string passwords. Perhaps something similar to the old replace tokens method would work? Something like [this](http://colinsalmcorner.com/post/managing-config-for-net-core-web-app-deployments-with-tokenizer-and-replacetokens-tasks)?
As to the EF migrations @Flex - would this be an environment variable that I toggle on/off if EF migrations are needed?

Comment: @Telvee32 The old replace token way should work for your scenario. Regarding EF migration, yes, just check current environment like env.IsEnvironment(xxx), then call EF migration (context.Database.Migrate())

Comment: OK, using FTP in combination with the linked article seems to work alright. The issue now is that I cannot clear the remote directory before the file transfer unless the application is stopped, which I must do manually. If the application is not stopped then the FTP task will just hang. If I have to log in to GearHost and stop the application manually (and then start it again) for every deployment then it kind of defeats the purpose of automated deployments. Do you know if GearHost exposes any API for this which could be leveraged by VSTS?

Comment: @Telvee32 There is the GearHost API that can stop CloudSite: [CloudSite Operations](http://docs.gearhost.apiary.io/#reference/cloudsite-operations)

Comment: Thanks @starain-MSFT. I'm currently testing the usage of this API with Powershell (though my Powershell knowledge is nearly 0). I am getting an Authorisation Denied error when using `Invoke-WebRequest` with the `URI` parameter set and the `Credential` parameter set to a `PSCredential` object. Needless to say the supplied credentials are correct.

Comment: @Telvee32 Using Invoke-RestMethod instead, I updated my answer, you can check it.

Comment: Thanks @starain-MSFT, that is all working now. One last thing, however - as GearHost requires a self-contained deployment for .NET Core apps, the deployment copies over a lot of .NET Core runtimes along with the application. Ever since I've started using VSTS there appear to have been a lot more runtimes copied over - the dotnet restore task alone takes quite a while, whereas the manual Visual Studio deploy would have the whole thing done in less than a minute. Application startup is much slower as well. Could it be copying surplus runtimes that I don't need, and if so can this be rectified?